# Matlab - Obtain value from outputFcn

Tags: matlab

I used Matlab to train a network. However, I want to obtain the accuracy value at each iteration. From the documentation, I have to define OutputFcn in the training option. Could anyone tell me how to get the accuracy values in a list?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far... Normally MATLAB Documentation involves examples of the methods.

Comment: I followed the documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainingoptions.html?requestedDomain=true. Here is my training option:

opts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'OutputFcn', ***);

I just don't understand how I can read out the iteration number with the corresponding accuracy to store them in a separate structure file.

Comment: Head over [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/customize-output-during-deep-learning-training.html). There you have an example of an OutputFcn. It must have one argument, here `info` which passes a structure. You can get the acccuracy from `info.TrainingAccuracy` and pass it on to further processing like plotting or writing to file.